# How can I push messages from WhatsApp to Twitter automatically

Tags: twitter, automation, whatsapp, ifttt

I've got a WhatsApp group that we use as an alert system. It is limited to 256 members. I want to enable more users to receive the alerts, so trying to determine how to get the messages from WhatsApp into another service (hopefully, Twitter) automatically. Every post that goes to the WhatsApp group is "tweet able", so no filtering or logic needs to take place. There is to open API for WhatsApp, nor any authorized "Bot" system. Any ideas? I'd be fine going to a intermediary service as well, where I could then run IFTTT to link the intermediary and Twitter, but so far I'm just hitting walls.

Thanks for your help!

David

ps. Please don't suggest another system (Telegram, etc.) as they all perform terribly above the initial limit size. This alert system cannot fail in terms of push notification timing accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I made an C# implementation of a web.whatsapp.com library: https://github.com/IwraStudios/Whatsapp-Bot

What you'll need to do by your self:

- Install one of the implemented browser(chrome/firefox)
- have a computer ON, to receive messages
- write some logic so only that group will be used
- pass it through to the twitterAPI

some code to get you started(firefox example): https://github.com/IwraStudios/Whatsapp-Bot/blob/master/FirefoxExample/Program.cs

EDIT: the library will only see the messages if the phone can, so the phone/whatsapp-app also needs to be online